# jquery tab container elements id issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have done a page using j-query tab widget. There are multiple tabs with same content (Tab-1,Tab-2,Tab-3....) in a single page.

When i am changing dynamically Tab-3 element by using j-query selector ($('#element-Id')), element changes is applying to some other Tabs element instead of Tab-3 which is current active tab.

I think this is happening as i have all element ids are common.

How can i select only active tab container elements without changing element ids?

Comment: Not really sure I understand your question.. can you attach some code?

Comment: first of all, it's not even valid html for elements to have same ID. They must have UNIQUE IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the problem is occurring because you are using same id's. Use of same element id's is not recommended and will always create trouble when code is binded to id.

Secondly the currently active tab can be distinguished from others based on a separate class or css visibility property that the j-query tab widget adds to the currently active element.